# Pass variable to Azure Devops template as parameter

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to pass a variable to job B that I generate in an earlier job, call it A.
The problem comes when I want to use that variable in a job referenced in a template.

I was able to use my variable in the job condition expression using this:

```
job_conditions: eq(dependencies.A.outputs['tag_validation.deploy'],'true')
```

but I cannot get the output of another variable, I have been trying this:

```
tag: $[format(dependencies.A.outputs['tag_validation.release_version'])]
tag: format(dependencies.A.outputs['tag_validation.release_version'])
tag: $(format(dependencies.A.outputs['tag_validation.release_version']))
```

```
parameters:
  job_conditions: eq(dependencies.A.outputs['tag_validation.deploy'],'true')  --> Works 
  tag: $[format(dependencies.A.outputs['tag_validation.release_version'])]    --> It does not work
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the way to do it.

I need to evaluate the expression inside 'variables' in my template.

```
parameters:
  job_conditions: eq(dependencies.A.outputs['tag_validation.deploy'],'true')  --> Works 
  tag: $[ dependencies.A.outputs['tag_validation.release_version'] ]
```

and in my template, I need to create the variables section:

```
variables:
    tag: ${{ parameters.tag }}
```

'tag' variable can be used later as $(tag)

Comment: Hi friend, thanks for your sharing and please mark your reply as answer. That will help other community members who easier search this useful information, it just a reminder :)